# Deploy node application to Google App Engine standard environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

Until december 2016, I was able to deploy node applications to Google App Engine standard environment with an `app.yaml` looking like this:

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
api_version: 1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Now, when I do this to deploy to a new project, I get this error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Deployments to App Engine
>   Flexible require 'env: flex' in app.yaml. The 'vm:true' setting has
>   been deprecated.

But I'm still able to deploy with this configuration for existing projects.

Has something changed recently in Google App Engine for Node.js ? (I don't know when reading the error message if standard environment is deprecated, or if for some reason it considers I chose to deploy to a flexible environment, and so I can't use `vm:true` because this option is deprecated for flexible environments).

Answer (score 3):

The `vm: true` indicates you were actually deploying to the flexible environment (an earlier version). The standard environment never supported node.js apps, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs.

Yes, there was a change in the flexible environment (all languages, not only node.js). See [Upgrading to the Latest App Engine Flexible Environment Beta Release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading). From there, explaining why your *existing* apps still work:

> Applications created with **vm:true**
>
> All applications created in the `vm:true` environment will continue to
>   work for at least 6 months after the App Engine flexible environment
>   becomes generally available. At that point, all customers need to
>   switch to the `env:flex` environment.

**UPDATE:**

Node.JS is currently available in the standard environment as well, see:

- [Now, you can deploy your Node.js app to App Engine standard environment](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/06/Now-you-can-deploy-your-Node-js-app-to-App-Engine-standard-environment.html)
- [Google App Engine Node.js Standard Environment Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/)

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that I opposed `vm:true` and `flex:env`. I thought `vm:true` was needed to specify options like `manual_scaling:
  instances: 1`, but it's not.